# How do I escape the Far Lands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm stuck in the Far Lands where nothing seems to load and I get kicked out after a period of time.

I'm trying to do a /home right when I'm logging in but I get a timeout before it even appear in the console and it doesn't seems to works, and each time I have to reset the server. Anyone have any suggestion to fix that without reseting the world?

Note: Yeah, I know I'm stupid to venture on the Far Lands but the curiosity won. :P

Comment: You don't. You're trapped. FOREVER! In all seriousness though, can you give any more information on how /home isn't working?

Comment: Simply because it's lagging so much I get a Timeout before it can even type it in the console lol.

Comment: You should edit that into your question, the information about timing out before typing is *really* important.

Comment: Wait, you actually walked all the way there without hacking your location in the first place? Wow.

Comment: If you don't have anything valuable in your inventory, you could delete your player data. It will act as if yo are a new player to the server, at spawn with no items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using NBTEdit to edit your location. Assuming you're running the multiplayer server, the file will be located here:

```
server/world/players/YourName.dat
```

...where *server* and *world* are the folders the Minecraft server and world files are in, respectively. If you aren't running it, you'll have to ask the administrator to fix it for you, though.

It may be a good idea to look at other player data and set your coordinates to the same as theirs.

Note that *I'm not sure if this will actually work, though*; I'm going off the assumption that the player `dat` files are just per-player `NBT` files, and NBTEdit is fairly old.

Here's the link to NBTEdit:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming that you're on multiplayer, so contact the sever owner and get them to delete your .dat file, this will reset you to the public spawn point of the server, you will lose all your items and maybe privileges and attributed area (depending on the mods) from doing this however, so this is a last resort (after asking them if they can edit it).

Comment: If the server admin is friendly, it may be possible to talk them into *editing* the `.dat` file rather than outright deleting it.  ;-)

Comment: @Ben I would have said that, but I didn't know if it was possible. If it is then editing is the better option.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a friend who can teleport other players (on vanilla servers, that means being an op and using `/tp <PlayerToMove> <DestinationPlayer>`), they can type in the teleport command ahead of time and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> as soon as they see you log in.  This will update your position on the server even if you lag out again; you'd simply be back in familiar territory once you logged back in afterward.

Comment: Not working because the server CPU is raising like hell and crash... I think that's what's causing the timeout.

Answer (score 6):

Since you own the server

> **I** have to reset the server

then copy your .dat file located in `server/YourWorld/players/YourName.dat`, paste it as a copy, and **then** delete your dat. Make a new .dat file with [INVedit](http://copy.mcft.net/mc/INVedit/INVedit.zip), enter your items one by one (the reason you saved a copy is to EXACTLY enter the stats as your previous), and then save it as "your username".dat (without the quotes) in `server/YourYorld/players/YourName.dat`. Then you can delete your copy. When you go back to your server, you'll be in the spawn point.
<sub>BTW, going to the Far Lands is a really nice job. If you went there legally (no server commands), that's pretty good!</sub>

Comment: Are you crazy, I've use teleport mods :P ... Who ever get there by walk without mods or hacks is a true no life! No offense but outside 500 000 blocks, the lag is getting more intense and will take more than 820 hours to get there for sure.

Comment: @Warface Youtube user [kurtjmac](http://www.youtube.com/user/kurtjmac#p/u/1/bKTEB3GCXAE) is a person who actually is documenting his whole adventure to the far lands. He even has his own website, <http://farlandsorbust.com>. Before you say no-life, he is doing a fundraiser for [Child's Play](http://www.childsplaycharity.org/).

Comment: Looks like you have done your Wiki search.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the server and have access to the console then you could use `/tp` from there to get yourself back to spawn. Just get a friend to log in and wait at the spawn point, then type out the `/tp` command, login, and hit enter right away. Hopefully you'll be able to get `/tp` to work before you get timedout.

Good Luck!

Comment: from the sounds of it, he can't get any console command working before the crash